# Array Sum & Avarage Key Problemphp

Tags: php

I have an array. I want to add and average to the directory at the same time. I have made many different experiments but have not come to a conclusion.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1608152389200
        [y] => 1397
        [z] => Value 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1610744389200
        [y] => 1483
        [z] => Value 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1619211589200
        [y] => 1505
        [z] => Value 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1624481989200
        [y] => 1666
        [z] => Value 2
    )
```

The Result I Want

[Value 1] = 1461,6 (Sub All Value 1 / All Value 1 Count)

[Value 2] = 1666

I would be very glad if you can help.

I experimented with the code below, but could not get the average.

```
   $Array = array();

    foreach($FirstArray as $value) {

      $Array[$value['z']] += $value['y'];

    }
```

Comment: _“but could not get the average”_ - well you are just adding values together, but so far, you are not even _counting_ how many values there were to begin with - so a very essential value that you _need_ to be able to calculate the average, does not even _exist_ in your attempt yet.

Comment: _Collect_ the values in an array first (so far, while adding them up, you did not even check if `$Array[$value['z']]` was actually set in the first place, before you try to “add” to it) - `$Array[$value['z']][] = $value['y'];` Afterwards, loop over that array again - and use `array_sum` and `count` to get the values you need for your calculation, for every sub-array in there.

Comment: Thanks CBroe I have successfully solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should post solutions in the Answer box, not edit them into your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
$SecondArray = array();

 foreach($FirstArray as $value) {

   $SecondArray[$value['z']][] = $value['y'];


 }


$SeperatorArray = array();

 foreach($SecondArray as  $key => $value) {

  $SeperatorArray[$key] = (array_sum($value) / count($value));

 }
```